# Use SOAP and REST API Together

Tags: magento-1.9, api

I will be involved in Mobile Application development for the first time and i don't have much exposure to Magento API. Our client wants a Mobile App to be built for Android, Iphone and Windows.

The requirements for the mobile app are as follows:

> 1) User LOGIN AND REGISTRATION
>
> 2) Connect with social media
>
> 3) Promotions: Promotional banner slider
>
> 4) Featured Categories:
>   Offer/Special categories with see all option and Scrollable products
>   under categories
>
> 5) SHOP LOCATOR
>
> 6) Category Listing
>
> 7) Product Listing
>
> 8) Sort Option
>
> 9) Popular Products, Special Offer Blocks
>
> 10) Navigation Filters
>
> 11) Real time product search
>
> 12) Item Listing
>
> 13) PRODUCT DETAIL with all product details and wishlist option
>
> 14) Review Product and Ratings
>
> 15) Add to chart and checkout functionality
>
> 16) Promotional Coupon
>
> 17) Gift Cards
>
> 18) Reward Points

I did a research on SOAP VS REST. Rest only provides the basic feature which is not enough to make an application with above functionality but on the other hand it is faster than SOAP.

Whereas SOAP has almost all the features listed above. Our client needs to make an app based on REST API.

Is it possible to use the combination of REST and SOAP API to build a mobile app? Can i use REST for Product listing, customer creations etc and use SOAP for rest of the feature?

Also, If it is not possible to used them together which would be better option to use SOAP which has many features or create a custom REST API where needed?

It would be great if anyone can provide some insight on this

Comment: Looks to me like you have it figured out. You cannot use RESt for everything so clearly you need SOAP. But what you can get through REST you can get through SOAP. But if you really insist in using both, you can use REST for retrieving products.

Comment: I was thinking of using REST for all the features it provides and for others i'll use SOAP. But my confusion is, Is it a standard practice? Can it create any complication? I have 0 experience in Mobile App so the picture is really vague

Comment: The only reason i am leaning towards REST is, it is faster than SOAP

Comment: I have almost 0 experience with mobile apps also but I can tell you one draw back from magento side. If you plan to use REST features that require a login (like retrieving orders) and you use SOAP also, you will need 2 web services accounts (one for REST and one for SOAP) and it may become hard to maintain later. So when you change one password you need to change both and so on.

Comment: thats what i was thinking therefore i needed opinion from someone who has worked with Mobile Apps, I thought you would have certainly worked with it.

Comment: Sorry for disappointing you. :) I've only used the REST and SOAP services from Magento for test purposes. And the only mobile app I've worked on has nothing to do with Magento.

Comment: No problem.. infact i feel little good about me.. Even MARIUS has no experience with Mobile App :P

Comment: @Dexter Question is posted few months before. So I think till now you might get the clear idea of your question. I am also in the same situation as you were! Now if you have solved your problem them please post it's answer. It will be helpful to other like me. :)

Comment: sorry dude. I still have no idea. Our company didn't got the project and so i didn't had to work on it. Though if you figure it out please post an answer here.